# Accessing generic class type outside instance of the class

Tags: swift, generics

This is my code:

```
class Person<T> {

    func printMyType() {
        // I have access to type T.
        print(T.self)
    }

}

class Child {
    let person = Person<Any>()

    func printPersonType() {
        // Where did type T went to? It doesn't compile.
        print(person.T.self)
    }
}
```

I am wondering why I don't have access to type `T` anymore of instance `Person` in instance `Child`. Why is type `T` gone? Why is it available in the method `printMyType`, but not outside of the instance?

Above was my question. Below is how I want to use it.

I want to know if it is possible to acquire the generic used type of `Person`, because now in my 'real' code, I need to repeat generic constraints:

```
class Person<T: Child> {}

class Child {}

// In this class, I want to know what Child is used.
// To accomplish this, I now need to create a type U to access Child
// Since I do not know how to access the generic type of Person.
class BirthGiver<T: Person<U>, U: Child> {
    let child: U.Type
    let person: Person<U>.Type

    init(person: T.Type, child: U.Type) {
        self.person = person
        self.child = child
    }
}
```

And I need to call it very ugly (duplicate code, twice `Child`, possible type unsafe?):

```
BirthGiver(person: Person<Child>.self, child: Child.self)
```

I feel like this should work

```
class BirthGiver<T: Person<U>> {
    let child: Person.T
    let person: Person<U>.Type

    init(person: T.Type) {
        self.person = person
        self.child = person.U
    }
}
```

So I can call it like this:

```
BirthGiver(person: Person<Child>.self)
```

But this doesn't compile, since there is no such type as `U`. I understand that, but is there any workaround? Repeating the generics all the time just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

After running this line

```
let person = Person<Any>()
```

`person` represents this **static** class

```
class Person {
    func printMyType() {

        print(Any.self)
    }
}
```

At the moment the class is instantiated `T` is (fixed) replaced by the type within the angle brackets